# Cosmos DB high RU

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I do have simple JSON data with an array, when I query array contains or join, the Request Unit is too high.

```sql
select value count(0)
From c
where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.signerDetails, {'displayStatus':0}, true)
and c.orgId = "e27dd002-bad3-4444-aa2b-855e5d4e79c8"
```

For the above ARRAY_CONTAINS query, we get 1882 RU for 40518 Count

```sql
select count(0)
From c WHERE c.orgId = "e27dd002-bad3-4444-aa2b-855e5d4e79c8"
and EXISTS(SELECT VALUE t FROM t IN c.signerDetails WHERE t.displayStatus = 0)
```

For the above exists query, we do get 1960 Ru for 40518 count

```json
{
    "id": "1b675bb2-f783-48a0-93bb-967a990b5204f901795b-d18d-4c2d-a68c-61adf7e8e8da",
    "orgId": "e27dd002-bad3-4444-aa2b-855e5d4e79c8", //Partition key
    "userDetails": [
        {
            "userName": "",
            "userEmail": "",
            "displayStatus": 4,

        },
        {
            "userName": "",
            "userEmail": "",
            "displayStatus": 1,

        }
    ],
    
    "status": "Completed",
    "_ts": 1619535494
}
```

Please share your thoughts on reducing the RU, or do I need to JSON data format or do I need to consider any other database for this kind of operation.

PS: I do have complex array querying, on the above sample I have removed the same for the code brevity.

Comment: What cost do you see for a query with roughly same result set and no ARRAY_CONTAINS clause?

Comment: The RU is just 3 for 40K count when I remove the ARRAY_CONTAINS clause.

Comment: That suggests the ARRAY_CONTAINS causes a scan reading all items, whereas without it uses only the index to compute aggregate value. I'm not sure how to avoid that, but you could consider adding a computed property to your model to query against, like `hasDisplayStatus0: true`. Then query against that simple value instead of array scan.